# Opt out bulk email option ignored

Tags: civimail, email, mailing

With our CRM the unsubscribe button adds a user opt out for the bulk emails.

The CRM still sends bulk emails to people who use the unsubscribe button or has the do not email and opt out of bulk email options.

Any help would be great.

Comment: There is an online documentation for this topic: http://gitbook.civicrm.org/email/maintaining-healthy-email-lists.html

Could you have a look at it and or and/or specify your problem?

Comment: I am dealing with the same issue also. Worst than that. People who haven't subscribed are getting the mass mailing.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't been able to recreate this issue on our sites, or on the demo site.

The test I did was:

---

- Add a user with an email address to a group
- Include that group in a new CiviMail mailing
- 1 recipient is displayed (correct)

---

- Change the user to have the 'No bulk email' setting
- Create a new CiviMail mailing, including the group
- 0 recipients are found (correct)

---

I couldn't see an automated test that ensures this (I've logged this on JIRA: https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-19473).

What version of CiviCRM are you using that encounters this issue? Are you sending emails straight from Civi or integrating with a third party email provider? Perhaps you could write out the exact steps to recreate the problem?

Comment: What about if using the token {action.optOutUrl}? This places a stop sign icon next to the email address in their record with a notation "On-Hold - Opt-Out" but they still are receiving messages.

Using CiviCRM 4.7.13 on Joomla 3.6.5

Comment: The tooltip for On-Hold: "Email Hold - 
This flag is most commonly used to mark an email address that is bouncing. If you are using the CiviMail component, emails that bounce excessively are automatically placed on hold and mailings are not sent to this address as long as it is marked hold. You can also set (or unset) this option manually - but remember that emails will not be sent to this address as long as it is marked 'On Hold'"